# How to pass args to JVM which runs tests with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I am a Gradle rookie and I am not sure whether Gradle will start the new JVM when it runs the test set.

Like [Passing JVM arguments to Gradle test task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776319/passing-jvm-arguments-to-gradle-test-task) I want to pass some parameters to the JVM running the test set.

I added the following lines to [build.gradle](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/build.gradle):

```
...
test {
    groovy {
        jvmArgs '-agentpath:/usr/lib/code_dependency_capturer.so' // add line
        srcDirs = ['src/test']
        if (!JavaVersion.current().isJava8Compatible()) {
            exclude '**/v8/*'
            exclude '**/vm8/*'
        }
    }
    resources {
        srcDirs = ['src/test-resources']
    }
}
...
```

But it tells me:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'groovy'.
Could not find method jvmArgs() for arguments[-agentpath:/usr/lib/code_dependency_capturer.so] on source set 'test' of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSet.
```

I googled this error but failed to solve it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try setting the `jvmArgs` of the enclosing `test` task rather than trying to set them on `groovy`.

The error you are getting suggests that `jvmArgs` isn’t present on `groovy`.

Example:

```
...
test {
    jvmArgs '-agentpath:/usr/lib/code_dependency_capturer.so' // add line
    groovy {      
        srcDirs = ['src/test']
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This is just a guess as I don’t have a gradle setup handy on which to confirm but worth a try as `jvmArgs` is documented as a property for `test`:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:jvmArgs

> `List<String> jvmArgs`
>
> The extra arguments to use to launch the JVM for the process. Does not include system properties and the minimum/maximum heap size.

Since `jvmArgs` is a list of String you can pass it multiple arguments, refer to:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_list_literals

Example:

```
  jvmArgs ["-Xarg1", "-Xarg2"]
```

For "-Dprop=value" system properties use the `systemProperties` of the `test` task instead:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:systemProperties

Comment: TL DR; jvmArgs is an array.

Comment: ... present on the `test` task not `groovy`

Comment: I need to run unit tests with different timeZone at one sub module. So I update like this: test{ jvmArgs '-Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.timezone="Asia/Colombo"' } But stil it's not getting what I changed. any idea?

Comment: Setting like this solved above issue.

test{
    systemProperty "user.country", "US"
    systemProperty "user.language", "en"
    systemProperty "user.timezone", "Asia/Colombo"

    useTestNG() {
        suites "src/test/resources/testng.xml"
    }
}

Comment: Original question wasn’t about system properties but I’ve updated my answer to show a few more examples and to highlight that jvmArgs is List<String> and linked to the test task docs which is the best reference @YAS_Bangamuwage

Comment: I can't making it work :/
```
tasks.test{
    jvmArgs("-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages")
    allJvmArgs = listOf("-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages")
}
```